# Prevent update of MDF file when attaching to newer version of LocalDb

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-6, localdb

I have WinForms app using EF6. The app use `LocalDb` storage (2014) because I need it to work from Windows 7 to the Windows 10.

And it is delivered with a `.mdf` file in app folder, and attaching it via connection string.

When I attach the `.mdf` file (created in SQL Server 2014 Express) to a newer versions of SQL Server Express, the `.mdf` is upgraded and I can't port it back to the Windows 7 anymore. That prevents me to develop app on multiple machines, because I can't make release copy of app with that `.mdf`, because it won't work on Windows 7 anymore.

Only way is to use SQL Server 2014 Express on all developer machines.

Is there way in connection string to prevent upgrade or that is needed for `.mdf` file to work on newer versions of SQL Server Express?

I'm thinking now to make `.mdf` file programmatically on first app start and execute script to make tables and seed data, and then attach that file. And I don't need to think what LocalDb version is used on that machine.

Comment: Your plan to have the database created and seeded at startup is probably the most correct way to go about solving your problem.  Another option would be to have the mdf file located outside your solution directory, so that it is always kept local to a specific OS.

Comment: Consider moving away from `.mdf` based deployments and towards using database projects/DACPACs (in other words, deploy through scripts). File-based deployment sounds convenient, until it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you **CANNOT** prevent or exclude the `.mdf` from being upgraded to the current internal database version when attaching to a newer server instance.

You need to **either** use the same version of SQL Server (Express / LocalDB) on all machines involved in the development - or you need to upgrade your existing database structure (and possibly static lookup data) by means of **SQL scripts** or Entity Framework migrations (or a similar, comparable mechanism that doesn't rely on internal SQL Server database versions).